# Use a CSS label as a link

Tags: css, label, clickable

I am trying to run a star rating system in my PHP script, which uses a radio property and a label to display stars.

Everything fine until this point.

What I really want to do is actually to use each star as a link to the corresponding script with the value of each star as parameter.
I shall notice that HTML elements are parts of a fieldset that is defined in detail within the CSS file.

Do you have any ideas on this?

This is what is currently produced from the PHP script

```
fieldset class='rating'

   input type='radio' id='submit' name='rating' value='5'
     label for='star5' title='Absolutely stunning'5 stars
   input type='radio' id='submit' name='rating' value='4'
     label for='star4' title='Suggested for everyone'>4 stars
   input type='radio' id='submit' name='rating' value='3'
     label for='star3' title='Pretty good effort'>3 stars
   input type='radio' id='submit' name='rating' value='2'
     label for='star2' title='Not Suggested'>2 stars
   input type='radio' id='submit' name='rating' value='1'
     label for='star1' title='Bad effort'>1 stars
fieldset
```

And this is the code in CSS that represents the Star:

```
.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';

}
```

I am sorry for formatting them this way, but there is a restriction as you know with HTML elements

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this.   Wrap the element in a span or div and write the css/jquery to fire on click of the element.

Comment: @BoltClock I just wanted to emphasize the important words. 

Brian Could you give me a simple example?

Comment: Can't you post your current markup to allow a proper answer?

Comment: I have edited my initial message